# Using strncpy() where destination contains the source

Tags: c, string, nested, trim, strncpy

I wrote a function to trim white space characters from a string in C.
My concern is the last line in the *trim()* function below, where the source is contained in the destination.  The test cases all turned out fine, along with some other testing.  Can copying all or a portion of a string where the source and destination are in the same memory cause weird problems?

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trim(char *line)
  {
  int  i, len = strlen(line);
  char *ptr, whitespace[] = " \t\n";

  // scan for first char which does not match a char in whitespace string
  for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    if (strchr(whitespace, line[i]) == NULL)
      break;
  ptr = line + i;

  // scan for last char which does not match a char in whitespace string
  for (i=len; i>0; i--)
    if (strchr(whitespace, line[i]) == NULL)
      break;
  line[i] + 1) = '\0';

  // copy result to line (this is the line relevant to the question)
  strncpy(line, ptr, len);
  }

int main(void)
  {
  int i;
  char test[4][64] = {
    "a line with no leading and trailing spaces",
    "  a line with some leading and trailing spaces  ",
    "\ta line with leading and trailing tabs\t",
    "\na line with leading and trailing newlines\n"
    };

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
    printf("test %d\nno trim: %s\n", i, test[i]);
    trim(test[i]);
    printf("trimmed: %s\n", test[i]);
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: That seems like a complicated way to string the string. Just loop while [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) is true, on both ends.

Comment: If the source and destination overlap, consider using memmove instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did consider isspace, but I want to keep the flexibility of delegating any character I choose as whitespace.  Was a bit overly complex, I dropped the dereferences for simple array indexing e.g. arr[i]

Comment: sorry, what is the objective of writting `*(line + i)` instead of the, more readable `line[i]` ??? for years, they have been considered equivalent forms to write the same thing, and you must agree that the second form is more readable.

Comment: @LuisColorado Please see my comment just above yours.  I did make the change in my source, but based on your feedback, I have also made the change in the posted code to avoid further comments which do not pertain to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `strncpy` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) you will see

> The behavior is undefined if the character arrays overlap.

You need to use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) instead, which is specified to handle overlapping memory.

Comment: memmove is perfect.  After some further testing I did find some odd behavior with strncpy destination containing the source.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, the second loop is erroneous.  I'll copy it here to show the exact place where it fails:

```
// scan for last char which does not match a char in whitespace string
for (i=len; i>0; i--)
  if (strchr(whitespace, *(line + i)) == NULL)
    break;
*(line + i + 1) = '\0';
```

One of two:

- or you rewrite the `for` loop as `for(i = len-1; i>=0; i--)`,
- or you write inside the loop the reference to `*(line + i - 1)`.

The first time you enter the loop, you get a `\0` character (the one at `*(line + len)` and it's not in the set of `"\n \t"` you used, so the loop always fails at the beginning, making you write a `\0` at position `i + 1` (this is undefined behaviour, as you are writing it past the `\0` char).

The discouraged use of `strncpy` on overlapping strings holds also, as has been pointed by other response.

### Note

`*(line + i - 1)` is equivalent to `line[i-1]`, which is more readable and less error prone.  And is perfectly compatible with the pointer definition you used in the function header.  C defines both expresions as equivalent.

On other thing, I don't know if searching a null terminated string (with `strchr(3)`) for character `'\0'` is undefined behaviour or not, but if it finds correctly the string terminator, you'll be lucky and won't get out of the `for` loop (`\0` is present in all strings, somehow)  As the manual doesn't say anything in respect to, perhaps somebody can illustrate from the standard.

Comment: While I agree with your assessment of the code mechanics that a '\0' is evaluated first, I have to disagree with the assessment the code is erroneous, and the proposed change introduces a segfault bug when trim() is fed an empty string "" due to the `i=len-1` or `*(line + i - 1)` when length is already 0. The reason the code is not erroneous is the whitespace string has '\0' at the end which [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/), according to the documentation, takes into account. I suppose for clarity, a '\0' could be added to the whitespace string.